# How do I get Secure Boot keys enrollment instructions for my firmware?

Tags: uefi, bios, openssl, secure-boot

I have Dell XPS 8700, and I can't figure out which file extension for keys is acceptable. After a few tries of enrolling PKs, the PC won't boot at all, so I have to reset BIOS setup. The local Dell technical support said it doesn't work with software (I mean, it isn't software, huh?)